# Why aren't the items lining up vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to line up my image and texts vertically centered.
One after another in a new line.
Specifically the left side, where there is image, text1, and text2
Ideally it would be

```
 |       Image      |

 |       text1      |

 |       text2      |
```

all centered vertically and horizontally

Implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid ps-md-0">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6 left-side">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
          <img src="../pictures/logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="72" />

          <h1>text1</h1>
          <h3>text2</h3>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6">
        <div class="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h3 class="login-heading mb-4">Welcome back!</h3>

                <!-- Sign In Form -->
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`d-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) and [`justify-content-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) to the parent container of the parent container that contains all elements. Then add [`text-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment) to the parent container of all elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid ps-md-0">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6 left-side d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png" alt="" width="72" height="72" />
                        <h1>Text</h1>
                        <h3>Text</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                                    <h3 class="login-heading mb-4">Welcome back!</h3>
                                    <!-- Sign In Form -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Learn more about [*Bootstrap Flex*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) and [*Bootstrap Utilities Spacing*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/).

Comment: how do I go about making it centered - centered, rather than centered - left?
notice in text2, it aligns left

Comment: @user I've re-wrote the answer, check it! if it's solved, don't forget to upvote and click the grey checkmark! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To stack the image and text on top of each other, use `d-flex` and `flex-direction-column` to make each div go on top of each other. Because the axis has changed from horizontal to vertical, use `align-items-center` to center the text.

To make it appear vertically, similarly use `d-flex` and `align-items-center` but set the div to the height of the parent with `h-100`. I've artificially increased the size of the body element as it'll shrink to the content, otherwise. Mark up below. You may need to go full screen on the snippet to see the example work

P.S. I'd avoid sizing images with html attributes. Better to use CSS these days.

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6 left-side h-100 d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" width="72" height="72" />
    <h1>text1</h1>
    <h3>text2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't the OP say "all centered vertically and horizontally"? I thought it was what I did in my answer (all elements vertical while horizontal to the whole page) or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Dunno. He said 'left side' too so I'm assuming the left side div has to be centered vertically in the viewport but the items with it to be stacked on top of each other and centered relative to each other. Perhap the OP can clarify? @user

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction:column` to the parent container with class `.d-flex`
(or use a bootstrap class that sets flex-direction to column)

Additionally, I noticed you have a lot of `!important` in your CSS.
It is good practice to eliminate as many instances of `!important` as possible.

Best of luck to you!